# C# object and string conversion

Tags: c#

I have following section of code in my program:

```
 object val;
 val = arr[1].Trim(); // in my case i am getting value here is 1.00
```

now when I am assigning value to a datarow I am getting error

> Expected int64 value.

```
datarow[Convert.ToString(drow["col"]).Trim().ToUpper()] = val;
```

I am not facing any issue when getting value other that 1.00.

What could be the exact problem? How can I solve it?

Suggestions and solutions are welcome

Comment: What type is the array of? Int, String, foo?

Comment: Insufficient code to give a meaningful answer. What is drow["col"]? Are you using the contents of a datarow to index the column of another datarow?

Comment: col is nothing but a string column name of datatable, yes Steve i am using content of a datarow to index the column of another datarow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that column in your datatable is expecting an `Int64` you need to convert `val` (which is a string) to an Int64:

```
var val = arr[1].Trim(); // String at this point
long longVal = 0;
if(!long.TryParse(val,out longVal){
    throw new InvalidOperationException("value wasnt an Int64!");
}
datarow[Convert.ToString(drow["col"]).Trim().ToUpper()] = longVal
```

Comment: thanx fro reply.. i tried this with my code, TryParse accepts string and val is an object so getting error of wrong types of argument..

Comment: @Pramod - no, val is a string - you've just typed it as object. I know it's a string because the return value from `Trim()` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

arr[1] seems to be string, and applying .Trim() keeps it as a string, even if it's "1.00". If you need an integer, you need to parse it. However, it can't be parsed to an intteger, because it's actually a double.

As a proof of whether I'm right or not, you can try (Int64)double.Parse(val) and that should work. However, it's up to you to decide whether that's not an issue for your program. There's two possible issues:

1. val might not be parse-able to double, in which case you will get an exception
2. val might be a double, but not one that can be represented as an int (too large, or lose precision ex. "1.8" would become 1)

Hope this helps

Comment: val in my case can have diffrent values, it can have emailid, phone number or amount, when it is falling in the catagory of amount and its vaues is 1.00 i am facing error.

Comment: Are they all int64? If so, then the above stands, with the added change that you need to cast that object to string first ie (Int64)double.Parse((string)val))